how to rotate only closest element to body?
I am a bit lost with all Blender version changes and I am trying to achieve the following effect:

in where the plane has the cubes as Instance on points, and I have an empty moving through which makes the closes cubes to rotate on z axis, but i cant make it work with the following geometry nodes:

I also have a vertexWeightProximity modifier but i'm not sure i am using it correctly:

When i move the empty through the plane they all seem to be affected somehow.
I tried changing the object in geometry node of last picture to Plane but it didnt change effect.

You're not clamping in any way your calculated distance and values derived from it, so  the bigger the distance the more rotation. One easy way to clamp values is to use "Map Range" node:


